# VirtualBox is crashing (BSOD) on Windows Guests. Please suggest me something else

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

VirtualBox is crashing Windows guests. (I have started to hate VirtualBox.)
My desktop is old and does not have hardware acceleration or virtualization technology. 
I have searched a little about that but not sure about anything in particular.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with LXDE and will be running Windows amd MAC guests too.

I am beginner in Ubuntu. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the same too as had the same issue sometime back.
I could not find anything reliable (for free) but VirtualBox. You may use VMware workstation 10.0.3. But it is not free. You have to buy it.

However you may download and test it free for 30 days.

Link: [Download VMware Workstation 10.0.3 for Linux](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=WKST-1003-LX&productId=362&rPId=6100#product_downloads)

On the same page, at right hand side, you may check the system requirements as well.

Alternatively, you can also try VMware Player. It is for free.
[Download VMware Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0)

(I have not tried VMware player and not sure you will be able to install it or not.)

Hope that will help you. In your research, if you find something better, please share.

Comment: You can also download VMWare Player, which is free for non-commercial purposes.  https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0